# Can't Display the data from AJAX Eager Relationship Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, eager

[image]Having difficulty to show the data from attendees table in blade view but in the network in the browser, it shows. In blade, it only shows the main model which is Activity and the data from attendees only outputs object. 
I need to outputs the data from attendees 

e.g. `attendee.fname`

I'm using yajra data tables:
 [image: here my browser info]

Here my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#student_table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "{{ route('ajaxdata.getdata') }}",
    "columns":[
        { data: "ActivityID" },
        { data:"attendee",name:"attendee.fname" } //cant show this need help
        ]

 });

  //Heres my controller

  function getdata()
  {
    //  $students = Student::select('first_name', 'last_name');
    //  return Datatables::of($students)->make(true);

    //$qr = QR::select('ActivityID', 'AttendeesID');
    //  return Datatables::of($qr)->make(true);
    //  $att = Attendee::select('fname','lname')->get();

    $qr = QR::with('attendee')->get();
    return Datatables::of($qr)->make(true);


  }
});

Heres my relationship

 public function attendee()
      {
          return $this->hasMany('App\Attendee','user_id','AttendeesID');
      }

public function qr()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App/QR','AttendeesID','user_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access relationship data in Datatables like as `{ data:"attendee.fname",name:"attendee.fname" }`

Comment: i have already tried that, but it is not working, the [object object] initially disappers.

Comment: You get data in object you get data like as $qr = QR::with('attendee')->get()->toArray();

Comment: it shows [object object] instead of the data. check my updated code up

Comment: console.log() and check your data which format then understanding how to collect data

Comment: Try this{ data:"attendee[0].fname",name:"attendee.fname" }